# Choose function for On-Policy prediction with approximation

Tags: reinforcement-learning, approximation

I am currently reading Sutton's introduction about reinforcement learning. After arriving in chapter 10 (On-Policy prediction with approximation), I am now wondering how to choose the form of the function `q` for which the optimal weights `w` shall be approximated.

I am referring to the first line of the pseudo code below from Sutton: How do I choose a good differentiable function [image]? Are there any standard strategies to choose it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose any function approximator that is differentiable.
Two commonly used classes of value function approximators are:

1. Linear function approximators: Linear combinations of features

   ```
    For approximating Q (the action-value)
    1. Find features that are functions of states and actions.
    2. Represent q as a weighted combination of these features.
   ```

   [image]

   where [image: phi_sa] is a vector in [image: Rd] with [image: ith] component given by [image] and [image: w] is the weight vector [image] whose [image: ith] componenet is given by [image].
2. Neural Network

   Represent [image: qSAW] using a neural network. You can either approximate using *action-in* (left of figure below) type or *action-out* (right of figure below) type. The difference being that the neural network can either take as input representations of both the state and the action and produce a single value (*Q-value*) as the output or take as input only the representation of state `s` and provide as output one value for each action, *a* in the action space (This type is easier to realize if the action space is discrete and finite).

   [image]

   Using the first type (*action-in*) for the example as it is close to the example in the linear case, you could create a Q-value approximator using a neural network with the following approach:

   ```
     Represent the state-action value as a normalized vector
     (or as a one-hot vector representing the state and action)
     1. Input layer : Size= number of inputs
     2. `n` hidden layers with `m` neurons
     3. Output layer: single output neuron
     Sigmoid activation function.
     Update weights using gradient descent as per the * semi-gradient Sarsa algorithm*.
   ```

   You could also directly use the visuals (if available) as the input and use convolutional layers like in the [DQN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602). But read the note below regarding the convergence and additional tricks to stabilize such non-linear approximator based method.

---

Graphically the function approximator looks like this:

[image: linearFA]

Note that [image: varphi_eqphi] is an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) and [image: xi] is used to represent elements of the state-action vector.
   You can use any elementary function in place of [image]. Some common ones are linear regressors, [Radial Basis Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function#Approximation) etc.

A *good differentiable function* depends on the context. But in reinforcement learning settings, convergence properties and the error bounds are important. The *Episodic semi-gradient Sarsa* algorithm discussed in the book has similar convergence properties as of TD(0) for a constant policy.

Since you specifically asked for on-policy prediction, using a *linear* function approximator is advisable to use because it is guaranteed to converge. The following are some of the other properties that make the Linear function approximators suitable:

- The error surface becomes a quadratic surface with a single minimum with mean square error function. This makes it a sure-shot solution as gradient descent is guaranteed to find the minima which is the global optimum.
- The error bound (as proved by [Tsitsiklis & Roy,1997](http://castlelab.princeton.edu/ORF544/Readings/Tsitsiklis%20van%20Roy%20-%20Analysis%20of%20Temporal-Difference%20Learning%20with%20Function%20Approximations-IEEE%20TAC.pdf) for the general case of TD(lambda) ) is:

  [image]

  Which means that the asymptotic error will be no more than [image] times the smallest possible error. Where [image: gamma] is the discount factor.
  The gradient is simple to calculate!

Using a non-linear approximator (like a (deep) neural network) however does not inherently guarantee convergence.
Gradient TD method uses the true gradient of the projected bellman error for the updates instead of the *semi-gradient* used in the *Episodic semi-gradient Sarsa algorithm* which is known to provide [convergence even with non-linear function approximators](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3809-convergent-temporal-difference-learning-with-arbitrary-smooth-function-approximation.pdf) (even for off-policy prediction) if certain conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. When I use a `ANN` and want to update the weights, one usally uses a loss function which will be minimized during a backpropagation process - what loss function do I choose in this case?

Comment: In that case, the loss for the Q-value function estimate (for the Episodic semi-gradient Sarsa algorithm as per your question) will be: `R + Gamma * q_hat(S',A',W) - q_hat(S,A,W)` for each step. Where `S` is the current state, `A` is the action that the agent takes in the current state for which the agent receives a reward `R` and ends up in the next state  `S'`, after which the agent takes an action `A'`. 
This loss term is listed in the pseudo code on the line where the weight is updated. Note that if `S' is a terminal state, q_hat(S',A',W) is 0.

Comment: This term: `R + Gamma * q_hat(S',A',W)` is called the *target* or *label* which is a common term used in supervised learning (for example using ANNs). Which makes the loss term easy to comprehend as : `Loss = target - predicted.

Comment: So I can train my network just with one by one sample as I need to use the current prediction of the old state to perform the current update? This means, that I cannot use batches - is this right?

Comment: Yes. Your understanding is correct. As per the *episodic semi-gradient Sarsa* algorithm, you would update the weights of the function approximator after every step of each of the episodes. 
In other variations for example using *experience replay*, typically some or all of the previously observed experiences (S,A,R,S',A') are collected/stored and used to update the weights in a batch rather than single example updates.